# What android structure should I use to populate ListFragment

Tags: android

I'm writing an app which will have list of elements and details of click element(in landscape mode). Data to populate my list i'm taking from internet. My question is what functions, objects are the best for such work since `Asynctask` is hard when I have to handle orientation changes?

Comment: Could you be more especific please, are you refering that the user clicks an element from the list and then it goes to the element's details on a landscape activity?

Comment: in Port mode i display details in new intent, in landscape mode after click i display fragment next to the list with details,but my questions regards what shoudl i use to populate data in background

Comment: For what you say, I see no problem of using AsyncTasks to get the data.  What is  the "hard to handle"  scenario you're saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use loaders instead of AsyncTasks. This way you can easily continue where you left prior to the otientation change. I have used these and QA is now finally quiet with orientation change bugs.

Here is the offical documentation, it's very detailed.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html